# Bigquery - How to keep partition in target table

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to select rows from a partitioned table and save the result into another table, how can I keep records' __PARTITIONTIME the same as they are in the source table? I mean, not only to keep the value of __PARTITIONTIME, but the whole partition feature so that I can do further queries on the target table using time decor and like stuff.

(I'm using Datalab notebooks)

```
%%sql -d standard --module TripData
SELECT
  HardwareId,
  TripId,
  StartTime,
  StopTime 
FROM
  `myproject.mydataset.TripData`
WHERE
  _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 7 * 24 HOUR),DAY)
  AND TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),DAY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this for multiple partitions at once!
You should do it one partition at a time specifying target partition - `targetTable$yyyymmdd`
Note:  first you need to create target table as a partitioned table with respective schema

Comment: well, that is a tedious work then. any plans on this feature for the future?

Comment: agree. let's see what google team will tell us. meantime you can leave this as a feature request at https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/

Comment: Yes, Google recognizes that this is indeed tedious (and costly) workaround, and plans to address it in the future.

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky that being said, I don't need to create a feature request any more right?

Comment: I think it is still helpful if you create one, so other users can upvote it and add their use cases to it.